# Running Ansible on Windows using Packer in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, packer, winrm

I'm trying to provision Ansible playbook using packer on Windows AMI.
That's my packer template:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "aws_access_key": "{{env `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`}}",
    "aws_secret_key": "{{env `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}",
    "aws_region": "{{env `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`}}",
    "aws_source_ami": "*****",
    "ssh_username": "{{env `AWS_AMI_USERNAME`}}",
    "aws_instance_type": "m1.medium",
    "name": "windows2012-...",
    "packer_dir": "/opt/packer",
    "home": "{{env `HOME`}}"
},
  "builders": [{
    "type": "amazon-ebs",
    "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
    "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
    "region": "{{user `aws_region`}}",
    "source_ami": "{{user `aws_source_ami`}}",
    "ami_regions": ["{{user `aws_region`}}"],
    "instance_type": "{{user `aws_instance_type`}}",
    "communicator": "winrm",
    "winrm_username": "Administrator",
    "winrm_use_ssl": true,
    "winrm_insecure": true,
    "winrm_timeout": "12h",
    "user_data_file": "scripts/userdata_setup.ps1",
    "ami_name": "{{user `name`}}-ami",
    "ami_description": "{{user `name`}}-ami",
    "associate_public_ip_address": true,
    "launch_block_device_mappings": [{
      "device_name": "/dev/xvda",
      "volume_type": "gp2",
      "volume_size": 50,
      "delete_on_termination": true
  }],
    "tags": {
      "artifact": "{{user `name`}}"
    }
  }],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "powershell",
      "script": "scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
    },
    {
      "type": "ansible",
      "playbook_file": "/path/to/playbook_file.yml",
      "extra_arguments" : [
        "--extra-vars", "ansible_user=Administrator ansible_connection=winrm ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I'm running `packer build my_template.json`
I'm getting the following error while the Ansible provisioner is running:

```
amazon-ebs: TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg":
            "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5986): Max retries
            exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x102ba6f90>: 
            Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))", "unreachable": true}
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong (why the host is 127.0.0.1?), but I haven't found any documentation about running ansible using packer on Windows in AMI.

Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong? How can I resolve my issue?

Best regards,
Adam

Comment: The traffic is proxied via packer. So Ansible runs on your local packer machine and connects to 127.0.0.1 (the packer executable) and which forwards the traffic to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the instructions in the documentation [Packer Documentation - Ansible: winrm communicator](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html#winrm-communicator) and use a custom connection plugin and use the following `ansible` provisioner args:

```
  "extra_arguments": [
    "--connection", "packer",
    "--extra-vars", "ansible_shell_type=powershell ansible_shell_executable=None"
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks!

Now I'm getting the following error:


`amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "failed to transfer file to 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible-tmp-1493043899.96-87816042318692\\setup.ps1':\n\n\n"}
    amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "failed to transfer file to 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible-tmp-1493043899.96-87816042318692\\setup.ps1':\n\n\n"}`

Comment: Hi @Adamba4, have you found a solution ?

Comment: @elhostis try posting a new Q or on the Packer email list, see https://www.packer.io/community.html .